# .selectable() multi-select from different criteria groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to figure out how to best allow multi-selection between two different criteria groups. Right now, selecting Yellow and Small in my example will return all Yellow and all Small elements. I am hoping to return the intersection of Yellow and Small.

http://jsfiddle.net/RKxj7/16/

```
.selectable({selected: function () {
$("#table-content tr").hide();
if ($("#Red").is(".ui-selected")) {
$(".color:contains('Red')").showParent();
}
...
if ($("#Small").is(".ui-selected")) {
$(".size:contains('Small')").showParent();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/RKxj7/19/

**JS:-**

```
function toggleSelected() {
    $("#table-content tr").hide();
    var colorSelected = $(".selector .ui-selected").length;
    var sizeSelected = $(".selector2 .ui-selected").length;
    if ((colorSelected > 0 && sizeSelected == 0) || (colorSelected == 0 && sizeSelected > 0)) {
        $(".selector").find(".ui-selected").each(function () {
            $(".color:contains(" + $(this).text() + ")").showParent();
        });

        $(".selector2").find(".ui-selected").each(function () {
            $(".size:contains(" + $(this).text() + ")").showParent();
        });
    } else {
        $(".selector").find(".ui-selected").each(function () {
            var selectedColor = $(".color:contains(" + $(this).text() + ")");

            $(".selector2").find(".ui-selected").each(function () {
                selectedColor.parent().find(".size:contains(" + $(this).text() + ")").showParent();
            });

        });
    }

    if ($(".ui-selected").length == 0) $("#table-content").find("tr").show();
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.showParent = function () {
        $(this).parent().show();
    };

    $(".selector, .selector2").bind("mousedown", function (e) {
        e.metaKey = true;
    }).selectable({
        selected: toggleSelected,
        unselected: toggleSelected
    });

});
```

Comment: @cardern - Does this answer your problem?

Comment: I don't think this approach will work very well with more than two selection groups... I've got 6 total (I should have made a better example) :/ If I add even one to your example it becomes fairly complicated. Also, is calling showParent inside toggleSelected a bad idea since it is defined in document ready?

Comment: I started to try to update it with a third selection group here: http://jsfiddle.net/RKxj7/21/. The if statement starts to get a little out of control pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

...maybe this one?

```
.selectable({ selected: function () {
        $("#table-content tr").show();
        if (!$("#Red").is(".ui-selected")) {
            $(".color:contains('Red')").hideParent();
        }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/RKxj7/37/

Comment: While that may answer the question it is better to include an explanation

Answer (score 0):

Adding .css makes it colorful and the size is as selected:
http://jsfiddle.net/kjelenak/RKxj7/55/

```
function toggleSelected() {
    $("#table-content tr").hide();
    var colorSelected = $(".selector .ui-selected").length;
    var sizeSelected = $(".selector2 .ui-selected").length;
    if ((colorSelected > 0 && sizeSelected == 0) || (colorSelected == 0 && sizeSelected > 0)) {
        $(".selector").find(".ui-selected").each(function () {
                 var colour = $(this).text();
            $(".color:contains(" + $(this).text() + ")").css("color", colour).showParent();
        });

        $(".selector2").find(".ui-selected").each(function () {
            $(".size:contains(" + $(this).text() + ")").showParent();
        });
    } else {
        $(".selector").find(".ui-selected").each(function () {
            var selectedColor = $(".color:contains(" + $(this).text() + ")");

            $(".selector2").find(".ui-selected").each(function () {
    var size = $(this).text();            selectedColor.parent().find(".size:contains(" + $(this).text() + ")").css("font-size", size).showParent();
            });

        });
    }

    if ($(".ui-selected").length == 0) $("#table-content").find("tr").show();
}
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.showParent = function () {
        $(this).parent().show();
    };

    $(".selector, .selector2").bind("mousedown", function (e) {
        e.metaKey = true;
    }).selectable({
        selected: toggleSelected,
        unselected: toggleSelected
    });

});
```

based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/19558160/3476753 (wiz kid)